# Multiple Forms on Same page AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having troubles on making this work. 
I need to have multiple forms on the same page... I've tried countless things, but nothing seem to work.

What I'm trying to do here is identify every form (in some way) in order to submit that one instead of the FIRST form on the page. Code below, works but submits always the same form, the first one!

Here's my current code

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit').on("click", function() {

        var artworkId = $("#inquirebox").data("artworkid");

        $.post("send.php";, $("#artinquire"+artworkId).serialize(), function(response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inquirebox" data-artworkid="<?php echo 456;?>">
    <form action="" method="post" id="artinquire<?php echo 456;?>" data-artworkid="<?php echo 456;?>">
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />

        <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />

        <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
        <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br />

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo 456;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="<?php echo $title1; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $uri1; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="artwork" value="<?php echo $artwork1; ?>">

        <input type="button" value="send" class="submit" id="submit" data-artworkid="<?php echo 456;?>">
        <div id="success"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So all the DIV's wrapping the form have the same ID then, all being `inquirebox`, and you're trying to identify them with a data attribute for some strange reason? When you're doing `$("#inquirebox").data("artworkid")` you're always getting the first one, as ID's are unique, and jQuery doesn't expect there to be any more than the first one ?

Comment: true. How can I've every form wrapper with a different ID and be able to Identify it with jQuery so it know wihch one I'm trying to submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same ID on all the DIV wrappers around the forms.

ID's must be unique, so you could use a class instead, but you really don't need any identifiers at all, nor do you need data attributes, the `.submit` button is inside the form, so all you need is `this.form`, or more jQuery'ish `$(this).closest('form')` to get the parent form

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit').on("click", function() {

        var form = $(this).closest('form');

        $.post("send.php", form.serialize(), function(response) {
            form.find('.success').html(response);
        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

You should however use a class on the `#success` element to find it based on the form.

Comment: WOW! thank you very much @adeneo. I was complicating way too much the whole thing.